# Averaging multiple values in a single column to create a new variable in a tidy dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a tidy dataframe that looks like the following:

```
id  item  value
1   e_o   4
1   e_f   6
1   e_c   5
1   e_lab 5
2   e_o   1
2   e_f   5
2   e_c   3
2   e_c   4
```

My goal is to perform a t.test comparing an average of the values e_o, e_f, and e_c to the values for e_lab. I am trying to determine the best way to manipulate the data in order to do this.

Specifically, I am not sure if it is better (or possible) to create an average of e_o, e_f, and e_c by staying in the tidy format and creating a new "item" variable like e_all, or if I should spread the data to get it out of the tidy format and then gather it to get it back into this format.

Ideally, I would end up with a dataframe that looks like this. **What is the best way for me to average e_o, e_f and e_c to add the e_all variable?**

```
id  item  value
1   e_o   4
1   e_f   6
1   e_c   5
1   e_all 5
1   e_lab 5
2   e_o   1
2   e_f   5
2   e_c   3
2   e_all 3
2   e_lab 4
```

With this setup, I would use the filter function to create two separate dataframes, one that only contains values for e_all and another that only contains values for e_lab. I would then use these two separate dataframes to perform a t.test. I am open to hearing about other methods of doing this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to `filter` the 'item' for 'e_f', 'e_o', 'e_c', do a group by `mean` and bind the rows with original datasets

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   filter(item %in% c("e_o", "e_f", "e_c")) %>% 
   group_by(id, item = "e_all") %>% 
   summarise(value = mean(value))  %>% 
   bind_rows(df1) %>%
   arrange(id, str_detect(item, "lab|all"))
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
#      id item  value
#   <int> <chr> <dbl>
# 1     1 e_o    4   
# 2     1 e_f    6   
# 3     1 e_c    5   
# 4     1 e_all  5   
# 5     1 e_lab  5   
# 6     2 e_o    1   
# 7     2 e_f    5   
# 8     2 e_c    3   
# 9     2 e_c    4   
#10     2 e_all  3.25
#11     2 e_lab  4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), item = c("e_o", 
"e_f", "e_c", "e_lab", "e_o", "e_f", "e_c", "e_c", "e_lab"), 
value = c(4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L)), 
.Names = c("id", "item", "value"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: What is the last line doing?

Comment: When I look at df1 after running this, I do not see "e_all" added to the item column. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @melbez It is just to order the rows in case you want to have 'lab', 'all' strings at the last for each 'id'

Comment: @melbez  I couldn't reproduce that issue.  Updated with the dataset used.  If you are saying that the original object is not changed, it won't unless you assing the object to the output i.e. `df1 <- df1 %>% filter(..`